Clustered bubbles or bubbles close together?
I am using OpenCV edge and contour to attempt to analyse the results of a shadowgraph of bubbles. It is working nicely but struggles when two bubbles are very close together, where it views it as one contour, when it is clearly two bubbles close to each other.
Contoured shadowgraph
Contoured shadowgraph with circularity condition applied
Above is the result of a circularity condition (which I found here), and whilst objectively the cluster of bubbles on the right is more circular, I would want in a perfect world for the bubbles in the middle to be identified as two separate bubbles and the clustered bubbles on the right to be ignored.
This is what I have as code so far:
img=cv.imread(path)
gi=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges=cv.Canny(gi,30,200)
contours, hierarchy=cv.findContours(edges, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            
circular_contours=[]

for a in range(len(contours)):
    peri=cv.arcLength(contours[a], True)
    area=cv.contourArea(contours[a])
    if peri==0:
        continue
    circularity=4*np.pi*(area/peri**2)
    print('Circularity: '+str(circularity))
    if 0.69<circularity<1.15:
        circular_contours.append(contours[a])
        
    

        
cv.drawContours(img,circular_contours,-1,(0,255,0),1)

this is the source image as asked for: 

Please add the source image (i.e. without contours drawn on it) to make you example reproducible.

You could try watershed to separate the two bubbles on the left.

I would calculate the convex hull of the contour. If it's a single bubble, the convex hull and the contour should almost match (since bubbles are convex). You can also compare the area the contour closes and the area the convex hull closes. If the areas are very similar it's only one bubble

that would be a good filter to detect groups of bubbles. you could then analyze the contour's curvature and find the concave inward peaks/corners. if it's two, you could split through those. if it's 3+... guesswork. "graph cuts" have been used to segment (split)... "things" along min-cost seams.
